# Error in recursive list logic

Tags: scala, recursion

I am trying to build a list in scala that given input (length,and a function) the output would be a list from 0 up to that length-1.

for example:

```
listMaker(3,f) = List(0,1,2)
```

so far I have created a helper class that takes 2 `int` and returns a `list` in that range.

the `listMaker` function is as follows:

```
def listMaker[A](length:Int, f:Int =>A):List[A] = length match{
  case 0 => List()
  case _ => listMaker(length,f)
}
```

my `f` function just takes a variable x and returns that:

```
 def f(x:Int)=x
```

**the comment below makes sense, but it still gets me errors. I think the edited code is an easier way to get where I would like to**

However, now I get an infinite loop. What part of the logic am I missing?

Comment: Your function arg, `f` states that it takes an `Int` and returns an `A`.  You are trying to invoke `f` passing in the result of `listHelper` which you stated returns a `List[Int]`.  You are trying to supply a `List[Int]` into a function that you have defined as taking an `Int`, hence the type mismatch

Comment: What do you think the non-zero case does? You need to call f with an integer, and add that to a list of length `length-1`. Instead, you're just calling yourself recursively with the same arguments => infinite loop

Comment: "However, now I get an empty list as a return" The code in your question as I write this does NOT give an empty list, but loops infinitely. So you're not running that code. We can't guess what code you're actually using, so it's not possible for us to say what you've missed.

Comment: I had an error in my test. I had not saved the new test case I wrote for that. So the empty list refers to something else. So now that I realized that, this specific case it does loop forever. I'll edit that...

Comment: f is of type A, and it doesn't take an int..

Comment: Yes, it does. `f:Int =>A` is  a function taking an `Int` and returning an `A`

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function typically has to gradually "bite off" pieces of the input data until there is nothing left - otherwise it can never terminate.

What this means in your particular case is that `length` must decrease on each recursive call until it reaches zero.

```
def listMaker[A](length:Int, f:Int =>A):List[A] = length match{
  case 0 => List()
  case _ => listMaker(length,f)
}
```

But you are not reducing `length` - you are passing it unchanged to the next recursive call, so, your function cannot terminate.

(There are other problems too - you need to build up your result list as you recurse, but your current code simply returns an empty list. I assume this is a learning exercise, so I'm not supplying working code...).

Comment: I have a helper method that takes in two int and outputs a list. I believe that I have to work that in this function. I am having difficulties on the listMaker taking f as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is a book exercise. I am just trying to pick some new skills in programming.