# Challenge in building a list in scala recursively

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

How to write a function, which builds a list of the given length. Each element is determined by applying f to the index of the element:

```
def buildList[A](length: Int, f: Int => A): List[A]
```

test case would be something like this:

```
test("test") {
def f(x: Int) = x
assert(buildList(10, f) == List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

So an input example would be listBuild(10,f) = output List(0,....9)

I'd know how to do this in OOL but functioning programming is a somewhat new concept to me.

Any ideas on  how to accomplish this? At least, the pseudo code would help..

PS: This is not HW. I have been trying to teach myself scala and this is a function I have been struggling with...

Comment: `I have been trying to teach myself scala and this is a function I have been struggling with...`

Keep going - I remember banging my head against the wall when learning fold 2 years ago

Comment: "This is not HW." If you say so, but it's odd that (at least) two of you have asked  questions about the same function today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204312/error-in-recursive-list-logic

Comment: `List.tabulate(length)(f)` is precisely what you want. But I do understand the point is to write it yourself

Answer (score 2):

It's preferable not to use recursion here.  You can get a sequence containing the indexes using a [Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Range).  Applying a function to every element of a collection is called a *map*.  Combining the two gives you:

```
0 until length map f
```

Comment: `"It's preferable not to use recursion here."` It's also preferable, I'd argue, to explain why "recursion" should not be explicitly used.

Comment: It's a matter of readability and idiomatic functional programming style. Recursion is only used when other methods are either not possible, or are much less clear.

Comment: Sure, Karl. It seems to me that, in the context of someone learning the building blocks of functional programming, jumping straight to a higher order function (like `until`) isn't helpful. Better to implement a non-tail recursive solution, I think. Then, write the tail-recursive solution, and then, use `fold`. Lastly, skip `fold` altogether when possible - only using higher order functions, such as `filter`, `sum`, etc.

Comment: `until` is not a higher order function. Neither is `sum`.  `map` and `filter` are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Comment: Personally, @Kevin, I think functional programming is usually so hard to learn because the most complex topics are too often taught first.  *Using* higher-order functions like `map` is much easier to wrap your head around than recursion.  If you were talking about *implementing* `map` that would be another matter.

Answer (score 1):

**building a list in scala recursively**

You can try something like this:

```
object UtilList {

  def build[A](length: Int, f: Int => A): List[A] = {
    val list: List[A]= List()

    @annotation.tailrec
    def foo(list: List[A], index: Int, f: Int => A): List[A] = {
      if (index == length) list
      else foo(f(index) :: list, index + 1, f)
    }
    foo(list, 0, f)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. k is an Integer and will never match against the empty list Nil.
2. Here is your function, use "buildLister"

   def listBuilder[A](k:Int, f:Int=>A) : List[A] = 
      if( k < 0 ) Nil
      else f(k) :: listBuilder(k-1, f)

   def buildLister[A](k:Int, f:Int=>A) : List[A] = 
      listBuilder(k-1, f).reverse

Comment: @user_456059239, in order to have the exact behavior, just reverse the list (edited)

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> def buildHelper(x: Int): List[Int] = 
     |  if (x < 0) List() else x :: buildHelper(x-1)
buildHelper: (x: Int)List[Int]

scala> def buildList(x: Int): List[Int] = 
     |   ???
buildList: (x: Int)List[Int]
```

Implementation for `buildList` (scroll over it to view it - but I'd try to implement it first on your own):

> buildHelper(x).reverse

```
scala> buildList(10)
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: This doesn't use the function `f`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most simple and elegant recursion list generation :

```
def listBuilder(iterate : Int): List[Int] = {
  if(iterate == 0) List() :+ 0
  else  listBuilder(iterate-1) :+ iterate
}
```